# 403 Nginx issue, serving files from /home/user/localhost

Tags: nginx, permissions, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to serve files from a directory called `localhost` under my home.

In my server block I specified `root /home/user/localhost`

If I change nginx user from `http` to my username it works but I have problems with php-fpm.

I want to own that folder and serve files from there, in my previous configuration it was working fine, now I reinstalled my OS and doesn't work, probably something in newer versions of nginx changed.

Already tried with `chmod 755 -R localhost/`, nothing...
Even with `chown -R http:http localhost` it goes 403, which however I do not want, I want to own that dir with my username.

I know this can be done and I've done it before without any permission issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Post your configuration, error log content and adequate filesystem structure. Check for SELinux missing policy/context.

Answer (score 0):

After further researches what I was missing were 755 permissions on my **home/username** folder.

Config an other permissions were fine but you'll get 403 if containing folder(s) isn't readable from outside.